# How do I make my build copy content from a referenced library to IIS express folder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-express, embedded-resource

I have a class library which makes reference to an xml file inside of a folder within the project called Content.

I have an MVC4 project that references the above class library and it needs information from that xml file.

When I run the MVC project (via IIS express), I get an error stating that it cannot find the xml file in the IIS directory.

I tried setting that file to "Copy Always" and the build action to "Embedded Resource" but it's not working. If I copy the Content folder from the bin\debug directory of the class library to my IIS express folder, it'll work

How do I set it so that it always has the content when I run my MVC application?

The solution structure looks like this at the moment:

[image]

Comment: can u show your solution structure? Is the xml file in the class library project? is it placed outside in a solution folder?

Comment: Yes the xml file is in the class library project in a folder called content. So Content/ConfigurationLevels.xml

Answer (score 0):

I set BuildAction to EmbeddedResource in same situation for my projects and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try using System.Reflexion, so the file is embeded on the dll then you can useit from there.

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();    
Stream strXml = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("App.Dir.File.xml"));
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(strXml);
```

"App.Dir.File.xml" refer the name space where the file are.